# Writing the Foo Function In LISP With the following Specification

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am struggling to find the right approach to solve the following function

```
(FOO #'– '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> ((–1 2 3 4 5) (1 –2 3 4 5) (1 2 –3 4 5) (1 2 3 –4 5) (1 2 3 4 –5))
```

The first Parameter to the foo function is supposed to be a function "-" that has to be applied to each element returning a list of list as shown above. I am not sure as to what approach I can take to create this function. I thought of recursion but not sure how I will preserve the list in each call and what kind of base criteria would I have. Any help would be appreciated. I cannot use loops as this is functional programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case of a recursion can be determined by asking yourself "When do I want to stop?".

As an example, when I want to compute the sum of an integer and all positive integers below it, I can do this recusively with a base case determined by answering "When do I want to stop?" with "When the value I might add in is zero.":

```
(defun sumdown (val)
  (if (zerop val)
      0
      (+ (sumdown (1- val)) val)))
```

With regard to 'preserve the list in each call', rather than trying to preserve anything I would just build up a result as you go along. Using the 'sumdown' example, this can be done in various ways that are all fundamentally the same approach.

The approach is to have an auxiliary function with a result argument that lets you build up a result as you recurse, and a function that is intended for the user to call, which calls the auxiliary function:

```
(defun sumdown1-aux (val result)
  (if (zerop val)
      result
      (sumdown1-aux (1- val) (+ val result))))

(defun sumdown1 (val)
  (sumdown1-aux val 0))
```

You can combine the auxiliary function and the function intended to be called by the user by using optional arguments:

```
(defun sumdown2 (val &optional (result 0))
  (if (zerop val)
      result
      (sumdown2 (1- val) (+ val result))))
```

You can hide the fact that an auxiliary function is being used by locally binding it within the function the user would call:

```
(defun sumdown3 (val)
  (labels ((sumdown3-aux (val result)
             (if (zerop val)
                 result
                 (sumdown3-aux (1- val) (+ val result)))))
    (sumdown3-aux val 0)))
```

A recursive solution to your problem can be implemented by answering the question "When do I want to stop when I want to operate on every element of a list?" to determine the base case, and building up a result list-of-lists (instead of adding as in the example) as you recurse. Breaking the problem into smaller pieces will help - "Make a copy of the original list with the nth element replaced by the result of calling the function on that element" can be considered a subproblem, so you might want to write a function that does that first, then use that function to write a function that solves the whole problem. It will be easier if you are allowed to use functions like `mapcar` and `substitute` or `substitute-if`, but if you are not, then you can write equivalents yourself out of what you are allowed to use.

Comment: Thank you so much this answer was really helpful. I was able to use the substitute and I used the Tail recursive approach using the auxiliary method and it worked. I am also allowed to use mapcar and substitute so that was a big help.

Comment: @HeartbeatDeveloper Glad to hear it helped. Note that using `substitute` will mean that you may get more than one value replaced. For instance, `(foo '(1 2 3 2 1)` would result in `((-1 2 3 2 -1) (1 -2 3 -2 1) (1 2 -3 2 1) (1 -2 3 -2 1) (-1 2 3 2 -1))`. This may or may not meet your requirement, and ensuring that only one element has the function called is not too much extra logic.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity you cannot use `loop` because this could be elegantly solved like so:

```
(defun foo (fctn lst)
  (loop 
     for n from 0 below (length lst)  ; outer
     collect (loop 
                for elt in lst        ; inner
                for i from 0 
                collect (if (= i n) (funcall fctn elt) elt))))
```

So we've got an outer loop that increments `n` from `0` to `(length lst)` excluded, and an inner loop that will copy verbatim the list except for element `n` where `fctn` is applied:

```
CL-USER> (foo #'- '(1 2 3 4 5))
((-1 2 3 4 5) (1 -2 3 4 5) (1 2 -3 4 5) (1 2 3 -4 5) (1 2 3 4 -5))
```

Replacing `loop` by recursion means creating local functions by using `labels` that replace the inner and the outer loop, for example:

```
(defun foo (fctn lst)
  (let ((len (length lst)))
    (labels
        ((inner (lst n &optional (i 0))
           (unless (= i len)
             (cons (if (= i n) (funcall fctn (car lst)) (car lst))
                   (inner (cdr lst) n (1+ i)))))
         (outer (&optional (i 0))
           (unless (= i len)
             (cons (inner lst i) (outer (1+ i))))))
      (outer))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Part of the implementation strategy that you choose here will depend on whether you want to support structure sharing or not.  Some of the answers have provided solutions where you get completely new lists, which may be what you want.  If you want to actually share some of the common structure, you can do that too, with a solution like this.  (Note:  I'm using first/rest/list* in preference to car/car/cons, since we're working with lists, not arbitrary trees.)

```
(defun foo (operation list)
  (labels ((foo% (left right result)
             (if (endp right) 
                 (nreverse result)
                 (let* ((x (first right))
                        (ox (funcall operation x)))
                   (foo% (list* x left)
                         (rest right)
                         (list* (revappend left
                                           (list* ox (rest right)))
                                result))))))
    (foo% '() list '())))
```

The idea is to walk down **list** once, keeping track of the left side (in reverse) and the right side as we've gone through them, so we get as **left** and **right**:

```
() (1 2 3 4)
(1) (2 3 4)
(2 1) (3 4)
(3 2 1) (4)
(4 3 2 1) ()
```

At each step but the last, we take the the first element from the right side, apply the operation, and create a new list use [**revappend**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revapp.htm) with the **left**, the result of the operation, and the rest of **right**.  The results from all those operations are accumulated in **result** (in reverse order).  At the end, we simply return **result**, reversed.  We can check that this has the right result, along with observing the structure sharing:

```
CL-USER> (foo '- '(1 2 3 4 5))
((-1 2 3 4 5) (1 -2 3 4 5) (1 2 -3 4 5) (1 2 3 -4 5) (1 2 3 4 -5))
```

By setting ***print-circle*** to true, we can see the structure sharing:

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* t)
T

CL-USER> (let ((l '(1 2 3 4 5)))
           (list l (foo '- l)))
((1 . #1=(2 . #2=(3 . #3=(4 . #4=(5)))))   ; input L
 ((-1 . #1#)
  (1 -2 . #2#)
  (1 2 -3 . #3#)
  (1 2 3 -4 . #4#)
  (1 2 3 4 -5)))
```

Each list in the output shares as much structure with the original input list as possible.

I find it easier, conceptually, to write some of these kind of functions recursively, using **labels**, but Common Lisp doesn't guarantee tail call optimization, so it's worth writing this iteratively, too.  Here's one way that could be done:

```
(defun phoo (operation list)
  (do ((left '())
       (right list)
       (result '()))
      ((endp right)
       (nreverse result))
    (let* ((x (pop right))
           (ox (funcall operation x)))
      (push (revappend left (list* ox right)) result)
      (push x left))))
```